# Facebook not returning all friends who installed the app

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working on an app where I need to get users facebook friends who had installed my app. I was able to get the friends successfully. But my client is not able to see me on his friend's list from facebook where I was able to see him. So after debugging, i found that facebook graph API is not returning me in my client's facebook friends list. But in vice versa, Facebook is returning my client in my facebook friends list... So, may I please know if anyone had any clue on this and can suggest me what to do?

This is happening only for few users, not everyone.

1. I have my client and PM in Denver.
2. I am in India
3. I and few of my colleagues had logged into the app with Facebook login and my client and PM did the same.
4. They are in my facebook friends too.
5. Now in my app when I try to get the facebook friends who installed the app I was able to see my client and PM.
6. But when my client is checking the app he was able to see only my PM but not me.
7. But my PM was able to see me on his list.
8. I was able to see all my colleagues and they can see me too.

This is the case.

Comment: Have all of you granted user_friends permission to the app?